# Nginx Equivalent of Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I've installed a PHP web application using a LEMP stack and I need to port some Apache .htaccess rewrite rules to the Nginx equivalents.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

I've tried these two services as recommended in other Stackoverflow answers:

- http://winginx.com/en/htaccess
- http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

This is my server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhp-2048.pem;

    root /var/www/example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;
#    return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

The first converter generated this which I added as an addition location stanza before the last curly bracket. A syntax check `nginx -t` checks out but Nginx fails to restart.

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$0 break;
  }
}
```

The second converter generated a different rule (below) which I added inside the first location stanza (under try_files) but that also breaks the configuration as Nginx won't restart.

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite /.* /index.php?/$0 last;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help to fix this is appreciated and welcome.

Update:
I still need help with this. I've not been able to get the first solution posted to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `=404` term in your `try_files` statement to `/index.php?$uri`.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;
}
```

Your `try_files` statement was only missing the final rewrite rule. Note that all URIs in `nginx` contain a leading `/`. Substituting `$uri` for `$0` should work for you.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are both rules generated correct? Which of them should I use with the updated `try_files` statement?

Comment: I changed the `try_files` statement line to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;` and now I get an error in the browser saying the site isn't redirecting properly.